# Python: image manipulation to video

Tags: python, image, video

I would like to create a video of image transformation. For example the end result is   .show("30% more contrast").

```
from PIL import ImageEnhance
enh = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
enh.enhance(1.8).show("30% more contrast")
```

I need 5 minutes video, 30fps, 1024x1024 of transforming original image to image with  30% more contrast.

I have no code for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here is an easy one to get you started:

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio
from PIL import ImageEnhance, Image
import numpy as np

fps = 30
n_frames = 5 * 60 * fps
increment = 0.3 * 1 / n_frames

# TODO: replace with your image
source_img = iio.imread("imageio:chelsea.png")
source = ImageEnhance.Contrast(Image.fromarray(source_img).resize((1024, 1024)))

with iio.imopen("slow_enhance.mp4", "w", plugin="pyav") as out_file:
    out_file.init_video_stream("libx264", fps=fps)
    for idx in range(n_frames):
        img = np.asarray(source.enhance(1 + idx * increment))
        out_file.write_frame(img)
```

For this to work you will have to have pillow, ImageIO, and pyav (av) installed: `pip install imageio pillow av`.

A faster way would be to generate the final (enhanced) image and to then linearly interpolate between the start and end image to generate intermediate images. This can be done in a batched and vectorized fashion, so it can be very quick.

Comment: Thank you. It does take some time.  Is it possible to create a video if folder has few images?  I want to add 100 more images to that folder and have only 1 video file as a result.